# Android Retrofit cant give me the data - How to Log Retrofit Request/Response?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I need to obtain the "product" data. When I get the response.message () it returns "ok", but the data I look for is not.
the API url format is like this: http://webhose.io/productFilter?token=789536e4-000d-4a3a-a7ac-223634f596**&format=json&q=in_stock%3Atrue

my problem was '%3A'
in the code its necessary to use ':' instead of '%3A'
thanks for your help.

Products.java

```
interface Products {
        @GET("{typefilter}")
        Call<Result> getProducts(@Path("typefilter") String typefilter, @Query("token") String token,
                                 @Query("format") String format, @Query("q") String filter);
    }
```

Activity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Service.Products service = Client.getClient().create(Service.Products.class);
        Call<Result> call = service.getProducts("productFilter",
                "789536e4-000d-4a3a-a7ac-223634f596**","json","in_stock%3Atrue");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
                Result result = response.body();
                Log.d("Result", response.message());
                Log.d("Result", result.getNext());
                Log.d("Result","quantity:" +result.getProducts().length);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: You can use http://facebook.github.io/stetho/ for debugging network request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this interceptor to log request & response

[Retrofit debugging with Okhttp logging interceptor](https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/06/retrofit-okhttp-logging-interceptor.html)

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. Now I need your help to solve

Comment: Yes please state your problem